# hoisting is not cause print, it throws an error, why?

Tags: javascript, hoisting

the next 3 lines throws an error:

```
variable=3;
console.log(variable);
let variable;
```

but I thought that the hoisting means that the 3 lines will be:

```
let variable;
variable=3;
console.log(variable);
```

I thought that the declaration moves up to the top of the scope...

thanks a lot

Comment: let variable = 3;

Comment: Hoisting exists for `var`-statements, not for `let`-statements